# Bootstrap 4 and user details - how to do the "bootstrap" or correct way?

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, bootstrap-4

I am working on a layout using bootstrap 4 alpha (really like the cards feature btw).

So, I have this area within the layout where I want the phone and email info to be placed on the same line.  I'm no css guru and know barely enough to be dangerous.  So, I'm unsure how to achieve the effect I'm after and do so correctly.  Any tips or advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="img/avatars/adelle.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <span class="favorite"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></span>
              <h6 class="media-heading">Jacqueline Perry</h6>
              <span class="company">Domino Technologies</span>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                    <ul class="details">
                      <li class="phone"><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg fa-lg"></i> (123) 786-4533 </li>
                      <li class="email"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i> jacqueline.perry@smithcorporation.com</a></li>
                      <li class="address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 338 West 23rd Street New York, NY 10011, USA </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- ./row -->
          </div> 
        </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this (see image below)

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/d1mdm2tk/3

Maybe this will work for you. Just re-size the view port and it will be one line for responsive you can adjust as you want. I'm using `row` and `col-*-*` because with `row` and `col-*-*` its possible otherwise you need to make custom css

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I don't think that solution will work - tried it but, not going to achieve the look I'm after.  So, what would custom css solutions be?

Comment: or try this one also  `li` parent inside it make `ul` with `display:inline-block` inside it make to `li` define its `width` as you want. 

For example:
`<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li><ul class="list-unstyled inline-block"><li>Here number</li><li>Here E-mail Address</li></ul></li>
<li>Here Your Address</li>
</ul>`

Comment: it is working fine. You can see demo on jsFiddle. You just need to resize demo frame. Check this one http://fiddle.jshell.net/hamzanisar/d1mdm2tk/6/show/ just adjust `padding` according to your requirement

Comment: **css** `.inline-block li{display:inline-block; float:left; padding:0 5px; /* as you want */ margin:0px;}`

Comment: Muhammad, Thank you for taking the time to answer my question(s) and provide some options.  I am sorry I haven't responded sooner.  I'll try your solutions this morning and respond back.  Sure do appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Removed a few "custom" styles I had that weren't necessary.  Your original solution is working pretty well after all - my bad :)